# How to intercept the FiveM JavaScript API request using BurpSuite

Tags: javascript, fivem

How can I intercept a FiveM NUI JavaScript API request using BupSuite?
The request looks like the following.

```
fetch("http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx/purchase", {
   method: "POST",
   headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}, 
   body: JSON.stringify(data)
}).then(res => {
   console.log("Request complete! response:", res);
   this.titel = "";
   this.beschreibung = "";
   this.telefonnummer = "";
   this.preis = "";
   this.currentPage = 0;
   this.getInserate();
});
```

I tried to intercept port 13172 and 30120, but it didn't capture the FiveM nui request.

Comment: What is "BupSuite"?

Comment: [BurpSuite](https://portswigger.net/burp) is a application for intercept traffic